# Full of self-reproach and self-loathing

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Full of self-reproach and self-loathing, the man put the gun to his head and pulled the trigger.

1. Is the combination of 'self-reproach' and 'self-loathing' more natural than 'self-reproach and self-loathe' and 'self-reproaching and self-loathing'?
2. Can you 'be full of' both?

Comment: Yes. _Self-loathe_ and _self-reproaching_ (as a noun) are not idiomatic English.

Answer (score 1):

You have to say it as you wrote it:

> Full of self-reproach and self-loathing...

"Self-reproaching" is not a noun (it's an adjective). "Self-loathe" is not a noun, either (it's a verb).

Answer (score 0):

A person or container can be full of a mixture, e.g. sand and cement, brandy and water, fear and excitement, etc.